# Is it possible to edit Component Links in SDL Tridion UI 2012?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

One big "Hi" for all humans from planet Tridion :).

I am trying to make component links editable in SDL Tridion UI 2012.

I have one component that contains multi-valued component links as one of fields.

When I put following in DWT

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="componentLink" -->
 <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex<3" -->
  <li> 
   <a href="#" tridion:href="@@RenderComponentField(FieldPath+"componentLink",TemplateRepeatIndex)@@">
    Link${TemplateRepeatIndex}
   </a>  
  </li> 
 <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Inside Template Builder as a result I got following:

```html
<li><a href="#" tridion:href="<tcdl:ComponentField name="componentLink" index="0">tcm:8-625</tcdl:ComponentField>">Link0</a></li> 
<li><a href="#" tridion:href="<tcdl:ComponentField name="componentLink" index="1">tcm:8-626</tcdl:ComponentField>">Link1</a></li> 
<li><a href="#" tridion:href="<tcdl:ComponentField name="componentLink" index="2">tcm:8-627</tcdl:ComponentField>">Link2</a></li>
```

As expected an error occured on "Default Finish Actions" on a page level

> Unable to find proper value for tridion:href

Is it needed to extract component links inside C# TBB in some previous action or exist any other way to resolve this( Enabling component links for SDL Tridion UI)?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to make the content of the linked Components editable, or the links themselves?

Comment: Never mind - looking at the code samples, it looks like the latter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my "new UI VM" I have the following code in a design:

```
<tcdl:ComponentField name="LinkText">
  <a tridion:href="@@Component.Fields.Target@@">${LinkText}</a>
</tcdl:ComponentField>
```

The linked Component is editable in the new UI. The tcdl:ComponentField is processed to wrap the appropriate in-context editing instructions around the link. You should be able translate that on to your code pretty easily...

Answer (score 6):

Thank you Jeremy, manually adding `<tcdl:ComponentField>` tag resolve this issue.

Here is final code that correctly resolve component links on a page level:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="componentLink" --> 
    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex<3" --> 
        <li>
            <tcdl:ComponentField name="componentLink">
                 <a tridion:href="@@Field@@">Link${TemplateRepeatIndex} </a>
            </tcdl:ComponentField>  
        </li>
    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```